# Reuse calculated column in WHERE clause

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

In a SELECT statement, I want to reuse a calculated column in the WHERE clause. Is there any way to do so in SQLserver?

Simplified example:

**Working, but with repeated calculation:**

```
SELECT field1, concat(field2, field3) AS calc_field
  FROM MyTable
  WHERE concat(field2, field3) LIKE 'A%'
```

**Desired:**

```
SELECT field1, concat(field2, field3) AS calc_field
  FROM MyTable
  WHERE calc_field LIKE 'A%'
```

Comment: Are you concerned that with your first example the calculation is being done twice?

Comment: @AakashM my concern is not only about wether calculation is done twice (not really sure about that. Is it internally optimized?) ...but also about re-writing same code several times in more complex statements.

Comment: Depending on how often you wish to filter this, you could put a computed column on the table.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There is no way to reuse the calculated field on the same level `SELECT`. You will need to nest it in order to use the alias.

```
SELECT field1
    , calc_field
FROM (
    SELECT field1
        , CONCAT (field2, field3) AS calc_field
    FROM MyTable
    ) tbl
WHERE calc_field LIKE 'A%'
```

[This is because of the order in which clauses are executed in a SQL query](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189499.aspx?f=255&mspperror=-2147217396#Anchor_2). As you can see in the way the clauses are listed, the `SELECT` clause, where the alias is generated, is executed after the `WHERE` clause.

Thus, the alias is not "visible" in the `WHERE` clause, because the alias is generated after the `WHERE` is applied.

Answer (score 8):

You can abuse `CROSS APPLY`. It is a part of FROM clause so its result could be used in subsequent clauses including WHERE, GROUP BY, SELECT and ORDER BY. You may also chain them so that the result of a CROSS APPLY could be used in the next one.

```
SELECT field1, ca.calc_field
FROM MyTable
CROSS APPLY (
    SELECT concat(field2, field3) AS calc_field
) AS ca
WHERE ca.calc_field LIKE 'A%';
```

You may also use common table expression (CTE):

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT field1, concat(field2, field3) AS calc_field
    FROM mytable
)
SELECT field1, calc_field
FROM cte
WHERE calc_field LIKE 'A%'
```

Answer (score 3):

Wrap it up in a derived table:

```
select field1, calc_field
from
(
    SELECT field1, concat(field2, field3) AS calc_field
    FROM MyTable
) dt
WHERE calc_field LIKE 'A%'
```

Answer (score 1):

Using sub Query to achieve this result:

```
select field1, calc_field from
( SELECT field1, concat(field2, field3) AS calc_field  FROM MyTable
) as dt
WHERE calc_field LIKE 'A%'
```

Answer (score 0):

For SQL Server you can use + as concatenation identifier

```html
SELECT field1, field2 +field3 AS calc_field
  FROM MyTable
  WHERE field2 + field3 LIKE 'A%'
```

For better performance avoid using concatenated fields in the WHERE clause. Depending on your requirements WHERE (field2 LIKE 'A%' OR field3 LIKE 'A%') might be a better option